# CrossBrowser test with IE not working in testNG

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I am trying to run a cross browser test in selenium using TestNG. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE. Script opens IE and on load, it points to URL -  http://localhost:16189/
It doesn't navigate to base url.

Below is my config from testng.xml

```
<test name="IETest">

<parameter name="browser" value="IE" />

<classes>

<class name="crossbrowserpack.CrossBrowserScript">

</class>

</classes>

</test>
```

Below is the instance creation code for IE in my code.

```
if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\IEdriver.exe");
                //create IE instance
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
```

Below is my test method.

```
public void testParameterWithXML() throws InterruptedException{
        driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com");
```

Comment: did you got any exception? if zoom level is not 100 then empty browser will come and does not navigate..

Comment: Thank you. IE was opening with 125% zoom and looks like that caused the issue.

Comment: yes zoom level is another issue to look for. posting exception stack trace will expedite in identifying the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls cross check your version of internetexplorerdriver and IE instance you are trying to automate.

Also add desired capabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Have you renamed IEDriverServer.exe to IEDriver.exe?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have renamed the exe file name.

Comment: Yes. I added the code for desired capabilities and changed the browser zoom size. Had to add a wait command to run test successfully on IE.